# Thread Command Line while maintaining Listener

Tags: java, sockets, console

I have a  Threaded client that is used for TCPConnections how do also continuously check for console input while still listening for connections.

Comment: You could use another thread to read console input.

Answer (score 0):

While this is awful broad i think this might be what your looking for:

```
    Thread t0 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            //Add code here
        }
    });t0.start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            //This will run the same time as the other code above.
        }
    });t1.start();
```

Tell me if im wrong. Your question is really vague.